# How to make a cell clickable and return the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I am new to stackoverflow so please forgive me if this is not informative enough. I have just been learning javascript and jquery for a few days now. I have created a table with some images, and what I'm attempting to do now is make it so that when a cell is clicked the value(src) or index number (single) will return.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#show_table').ready(function(){
          
        //instantiate variables
        var images =["auburn.png","beige.png","black.png","blue.png","bright_pink.png","bright_yellow.png","copper.png","dark_brown.png","dark_green.png",
                     "dark_navy.png","date.png","emerald.png","erin_green.png","green.png","grey.png","lavender.png","lemon.png","light_brown.png","light_grey.png",
                     "light_pink.png","medium_pink.png","ming.png","mint.png","mulberry.png","off_white.png","orange.png","orange_gold.png","pro_saxon.png",
                     "purple.png","red.png","royal_blue.png","russett.png","seafoam.png","slate_blue.png","sunflower.png"];
        //var img_longth = images.length;
        var str = [];
        var index = 0;
        var i = 0;
        //2 for loops to create table and assign each image a index number
        for(var row=0;row<9;row++){
             str +='<tr>';
            for(var col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                //
                //puts images into each cell within the table
                if(index < images.length){
                    str +='<td><img src="images/thread_squares/'+images[index]+'"></td>';
                    index++;
                }
            }   str +='</tr>';
        } 
            $('#show_table').html(str);
            //alert(i);
            
        //allows user to click specific color then returns the value
        //also shows and hides table and designs in index.php
        $('#show_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
            alert(images);
            //alert("looking good"); 
            $("#show_table").hide();
        });
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='show_table'></table>
```

So far for returns I have recieved, all image items in the array, the number of items in the array or [Object Object]. I appreciate the help and if there is anymore information needed I will do my best so supply it. Thank you.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/L4wmnybr/ ?

Comment: Yeah it works perfect thank you so much!! been trying to do this for 2 days now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of src in an image element, first you need to select the correct element **img** to get the value.

You ca do it many ways, but here i have attached the click event with **td** of the table.

In the click event you can select the clicked **td** element by $(this) and then you can get the child image element using $(this).

Once you get the image tag you can get the src attribute , for index
you can store the index of the image in an attribute of the image element and later you can retrieve it.

Check the updated snippet.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#show_table').ready(function(){
          
        //instantiate variables
        var images =["auburn.png","beige.png","black.png","blue.png","bright_pink.png","bright_yellow.png","copper.png","dark_brown.png","dark_green.png",
                     "dark_navy.png","date.png","emerald.png","erin_green.png","green.png","grey.png","lavender.png","lemon.png","light_brown.png","light_grey.png",
                     "light_pink.png","medium_pink.png","ming.png","mint.png","mulberry.png","off_white.png","orange.png","orange_gold.png","pro_saxon.png",
                     "purple.png","red.png","royal_blue.png","russett.png","seafoam.png","slate_blue.png","sunflower.png"];
        //var img_longth = images.length;
        var str = [];
        var index = 0;
        var i = 0;
        //2 for loops to create table and assign each image a index number
        for(var row=0;row<9;row++){
             str +='<tr>';
            for(var col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                //
                //puts images into each cell within the table
                if(index < images.length){
                    str +='<td><img src="images/thread_squares/'+images[index]+'" imageIndex="'+ index+'"></td>';
                    index++;
                }
            }   str +='</tr>';
        } 
            $('#show_table').html(str);
            //alert(i);
            
        //allows user to click specific color then returns the value
        //also shows and hides table and designs in index.php
        $('#show_table tbody').on('click', 'td', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
         
           alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
            alert($(this).children('img').attr('imageIndex'));
           
        });
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='show_table'></table>
```

Comment: Glad that i could help :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works well for you. It will help others to reach the solution quickly who are searching for a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry about that I just did thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#show_table').ready(function(){
          
        //instantiate variables
        var images =["auburn.png","beige.png","black.png","blue.png","bright_pink.png","bright_yellow.png","copper.png","dark_brown.png","dark_green.png",
                     "dark_navy.png","date.png","emerald.png","erin_green.png","green.png","grey.png","lavender.png","lemon.png","light_brown.png","light_grey.png",
                     "light_pink.png","medium_pink.png","ming.png","mint.png","mulberry.png","off_white.png","orange.png","orange_gold.png","pro_saxon.png",
                     "purple.png","red.png","royal_blue.png","russett.png","seafoam.png","slate_blue.png","sunflower.png"];
        //var img_longth = images.length;
        var str = [];
        var index = 0;
        var i = 0;
        //2 for loops to create table and assign each image a index number
        for(var row=0;row<9;row++){
             str +='<tr>';
            for(var col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                //
                //puts images into each cell within the table
                if(index < images.length){
                    str +='<td><img src="images/thread_squares/'+images[index]+'"></td>';
                    index++;
                }
            }   str +='</tr>';
        } 
            $('#show_table').html(str);
            //alert(i);
            
        //allows user to click specific color then returns the value
        //also shows and hides table and designs in index.php
        $('#show_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
            alert(event.target.src);
            //alert("looking good"); 
            $("#show_table").hide();
        });
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='show_table'></table>
```

Comment: Mind adding a comment explaining what OP was doing wrong, and how you fixed it?

Comment: I meant, can you add the explanation to the body of your answer? Code-only answers with no accompanying explanation tend to be discouraged.